# Diferença entre formas de importar com e sem 'package:'

Tags: flutter, dart

Quando importamos uma classe/biblioteca é sugeridos duas opções, gostaria de saber se existe alguma diferença/vantagem entre importar classes/libs informando diretamente o caminho e com a 'comando' `package:`

Ex:

```
import 'controller/conferencia_controller.dart';
import 'package:conferencia/controller/conferencia_controller.dart';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seguinte import :

```
import 'controller/conferencia_controller.dart';
```

É um import **relativo**. Isso quer dizer que o caminho especificado é relativo ao arquivo que está fazendo o import. Inclusive, também é possível fazer imports usando `..`que significa subir um diretório:

```
import '../controller/conferencia_controller.dart';
```

Esse tipo de import funciona, e para projetos pequenos não deve gerar muitos problemas. Mas caso um arquivo mude de caminho, esse import vai quebrar. Isso significa que você vai ter que re-olhar todos os locais que você fez esse import e adequar-se à modificação. Bem, existem IDE's que fazem isso automaticamente, e não sei até que ponto cada uma consegue discernir.

Porém, isso não pode ser feito sempre. Quando cria-se um novo pacote (e isso inclui seu próprio projeto), [o diretório /lib é o que fica público para acessar externamente.](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/create-library-packages#what-makes-a-library-package) Normalmente, nesse diretório fica só o que deve ser visível para quem quiser importar seu pacote futuramente, exportando os arquivos necessários. Além disso, é comum unificar todos os exports em um único arquivo .dart, para ser necessário apenas um import isolado, referente as funcionalidades daquele pacote.

> Diretamente dentro de /lib, o arquivo principal da biblioteca, shelf.dart, exporta inúmeros arquivos de lib/src.
>
> (Mesmo site linkado acima, tradução livre)

Isto é, se você quer importar um arquivo de dentro de um pacote, de fora dele, ou vice-versa, [você precisa usar o segundo método de import (referenciando qual package ele é)](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/create-library-packages#importing-library-files):

`import 'package:utilities/utilities.dart';`

Este segundo tipo de import, permite imports apenas do que é público ao pacote, isto é, dentro da pasta `/lib`, e independe da relação de caminho entre os arquivos.

Segundo o site linkado:

> When in doubt, use the package: directive; it works in all cases.
>
> (Quando em dúvida, use o import "package:"; Funciona em todos os casos

Portanto, uma convenção mais sadia é a de usar o segundo tipo sempre. Bem, em projetos pequenos não deve prejudicar muito não o fazer, desde que tendo a noção do que está sendo feito.

Answer (score 1):

Na primeira opção não está a ser feita referência à root do projecto. Se o ficheiro (que está a importar outro) onde tens este importe for movido para outro directório, o import deixará de funcionar.

Vamos supor que um ficheiro `main.dart` que está guardado na root do nosso project, e em paralelo tem outros ficheiros, e um directório chamado `controller/`. Dentro deste directório temos o ficheiro que estamos aqui a importar:

```
import 'controller/conferencia_controller.dart';
```

Se entretanto decidíssemos mudar o nosso `main.dart` para outro directório, já não teríamos acesso directo ao directório `controller/` e o nosso import iria dar erro.

No entanto, se seguirmos a segunda opção de import que referencia a root do projecto (`package:conferencia`):

```
import 'package:conferencia/controller/conferencia_controller.dart';
```

Podemos mudar o nosso `main.dart` para qualquer directório do nosso projecto, que a referência irá estar sempre correcta.

Comment: Opa João, você  poderia explicar melhor? Colocar um exemplo?

Comment: Já editei a resposta para clarificar e dar exemplos.